# How to convert a string to double floating-point value?

Tags: c, function

sorry if the title is confusing, I just need some experienced programmers to attempt to clarify something for me. So one of my homework questions asks me this (the language is c):

Write a function  that receives a string and returns a double floating-point value. The fucntion declaration would look like this

```
double convertFloat(char s[]);
```

Do not use the strtol() function or any other standard c library function. Write your own!... Note that the input string could have any of the following sample formats: "1.34", "-1.4554", "6".

I am just not sure how to approach this because I am not sure what is being asked here. If I had to write a function to find a square root or something like that I could do it no problem but it seems that I have to take strings that are all numbers and convert them to floats... just not sure where to start and googling similar things has yielded no results.
Thank you all in advance.
- Davey

Comment: First write down a precise description of what floating point string is.  Sign, digits, decimal point, more digits.  Then go from left to right converting characters to numbers.

Comment: You need to parse a string, Check 1st char if '-' or not, then convert all number chars to number (subtract from ASCII '0') multiply by power of 10 based on position.  Do the same for digits after '.' but power of 10 to negative exponent.

Comment: You should analyze the string one char (digit) at a time. For example, the first char is "1": so the result is now 1. Next there is the char "2". Ah! The old result must be multiplied by 10, then the 2 is added. So the result now is 12. And so on. The optional sign and the dot must be managed also, but this is a first skeleton.

Comment: Are there any actual requirements about *what* it should return, other than the type?

Comment: @harold I believe it wants to return the same characters but as a float instead of an Array of chars

Comment: @OldProgrammer that's what I was thinking but I just couldn't figure out how I would do that... My only thought was a long if/else chain checking each char if it was a specific digit and then adding that to some sort of accumulating sum

Comment: @DaveyMcGinnis so not characters then. A float doesn't have characters. But the part "the same" is actually really interesting, because many strings do not parse to a float exactly (such as the infamous 0.1), so you can't ask for it to be exactly equal.

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing

```
unsigned int convertUnsignedInt(const char *s);
// e.g. convertUnsignedInt("42") == 42
```

It's a bit simpler because you don't have to handle negative numbers or fractions, but it shows the general principle.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the complete code to your problem. The code is understandable. Ask if you have any doubts regarding it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int n, int m)
{
    if (m == 1)
        return n;
    else
        return n * (power(n, m - 1));
}

int getLength(char s[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++);
    return i;
}

double convertFloat(char s[])
{
    int len = getLength(s);
    int dotpos = 0;
    double result = 0.0f;
    int n = 0, flag = 0;
    if(s[0] == '-')
    {
        n = 1;
        flag = 1;
    }
    for (; n < len; n++)
    {
        if (s[n] == '.')
        {
            dotpos = len - n - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            result = result * 10 + (s[n] - '0');
        }
    }
    result /= power(10, dotpos);
    if(flag)
        return result*-1;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "126433.47";
    printf("%f", convertFloat(str));
}
```